# Add default axios header after login nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

I'm using Next.js for my app, and currently have an API route that sets a JWT as a cookie. Throughout the app, I'm using Axios to fetch all of my data from external APIs, and after a user logs in I need to set that cookie as a default request header on every API call to make sure that a user has been authenticated. The basic flow is like this:

The login form sends a post request to my API route at `/api/auth/login`, passing the username and password and returning the JWT, and setting it as a cookie. Once the `idToken` cookie has been set I need to add that as an authentication header to every API request within my Axios instance, seen as `adapter` here. How can I go about getting this done?

My handle login function:

```
const handleLogin = async (values: ValuesProps) => {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/login', values);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
};
```

Which speaks to `api/auth/login`:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { setCookie, parseCookies } from 'nookies';
import { adapter } from 'utils/api/config';

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    res.status(500).json('Only POST requests allowed at this route.');
  } else {
    const { data } = await adapter.post(AUTH.login, JSON.stringify(req.body));
    const cookies = parseCookies();

    setCookie({ res }, 'idToken', data.token, {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
      path: '/',
    });

    api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${cookies['idToken']}`

    res.status(200).json(data);
  }
};

export default handler;
```

As you see here I tried adding `adapter.defaults.headers.Authorization` as a global default, but I'm not seeing it in my request headers. What's the best way to go about setting this globally?

Comment: You can use Axios interceptors

Comment: I figured as much, but how would I get the cookie and pass that in? The cookie was returning undefined when I tried interceptors.

Comment: collect JWT from the response interceptor and place it inside the request intercepter

Comment: Do you have an example/documentation?

Comment: guide: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: Does the `withCredentials` property get this done too? Otherwise how can I pass from the `response` to the `request`.

Comment: on Sign In, save JWT in cookie or localStorage then get value from a cookie or localStorage & pass inside the header of request interceptor

Comment: @JesseWinton did you manage to solve it. I am having the same problem, i am using axios interceptors and i already have my tokens stored in cookies, but when i try to get then in my interceptor i keep getting undefined and therefore my requests fail because there is no token in the header.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `axios.create`. It is a factory that creates new instances of axios.
It looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const axiosInstance = async () => {
  // You need to be careful in next.js for adding cookies.
  // You could be on the server or a client. This code will work for the client assuming you will use it on the client side.
  // I believe you are using `parser` to get cookies. get the token.
  const yourToken = "whatever";
  const axiosClient = axios.create({
      baseURL: 'baseUrlHere',
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/vnd.GitHub.v3+json',
          // This is how u set in your code
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies['idToken']}`
      }
   });

   return axiosClient;
}
```

Then import this anywhere you want to use it:

```
 const { data } = await axiosInstance().post("/auth");
```

Technically this should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can set default header to all axios request by command:

```
const token = getCookie('token')
axios.defaults.headers.common["idToken"] = token
```